# Mango leaf disease

Tags: diseases, fungus, mango

My mango plant has various symptoms so I'm not able to pinpoint the disease. Is it just a result of anthracnose or is it a lesser problem?
[image: img1]
[image: img2]
[image: img3]
[image: img4]

I sprayed some Bonide copper fungicide. Is there a better solution by any chance?